# systemd-resolve reset after wake from suspend

Tags: suspend, dns, systemd-resolved, wireguard

I'm using wireguard client with the following PostUp script:

```
PostUp = systemd-resolve -i %i --set-dns=x.x.x.x --set-domain=~.
```

`systemd-resolve` did set the DNS setting correctly and `127.0.0.53` was able to resolve domain.

```
$ resolvectl status
Link 5 (wg1)
      Current Scopes: DNS
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: yes
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: x.x.x.x
         DNS Servers: x.x.x.x
          DNS Domain: ~.
```

But the DNS setting reset after wake from suspend:

```
$ resolvectl status
Link 5 (wg1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: yes
    DNSSEC supported: yes
```

I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1322045/how-to-persist-systemd-resolve-configuration-for-a-particular-network-interfac/1365864), but this is about making the config persists across suspend, not reboot. In my case, the DNS setting does persist across reboot.

I'm using Ubuntu's wireguard, not the ppa.

```
$ apt search wireguard
wireguard/eoan,eoan,now 0.0.20190913-1ubuntu1 all [installed]
wireguard-dkms/eoan,eoan,now 0.0.20190913-1ubuntu1 all [installed,automatic]
wireguard-tools/eoan,now 0.0.20190913-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

Edit: Same issue with launchpad version.

```
wireguard/eoan,eoan,now 0.0.20191012-wg1~eoan all [installed]
wireguard-dkms/eoan,eoan,now 0.0.20191012-wg1~eoan all [installed,automatic]
wireguard-tools/eoan,now 0.0.20191012-wg1~eoan amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

I tried several workarounds, none of them worked.

1. `/etc/systemd/network/wireguard.network`

```
[Match]
Name=wg1

[Network]
DNS=x.x.x.x
Domains=~.
```

While this approach did set the DNS for wireguard interface, systemd-resolved fallback to eth0's DNS after wake.

```
$ resolvectl status
Link 5 (wg1)
      Current Scopes: none
  Current DNS Server: x.x.x.x
         DNS Servers: x.x.x.x

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
  Current DNS Server: y.y.y.y
         DNS Servers: y.y.y.y
```

2. Run a script after wake from suspend, `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/wireguard-dns`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    exit 0
    ;;
  post/*)
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here
    systemd-resolve -i wg1 --set-dns=x.x.x.x --set-domain=~.
    ;;
esac
```

This workaround didn't work, the DNS config still reset after wake. I did verify the script did get executed (I tested with `echo "script executed" > /home/user/output`, file was there with the text), but somehow it had no effect.

Similar script in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` only worked for a few seconds (after wake), then the config reset and fallback to eth0's DNS.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in 
        thaw|resume)
                systemd-resolve -i wg1 --set-dns=x.x.x.x --set-domain=~.
        ;;
esac
```

3. Tried another wake-from-suspend script, same result as no. 1.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "pre" ] && [ "$2" = "suspend" ]; then
    wg-quick down wg1
elif [ "$1" = "post" ] && [ "$2" = "suspend" ]; then
    wg-quick up wg1
fi
```

Edit: Same issue on fresh install.

Edit: Also affects 19.04, tried on fresh install.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/pm-action.8.html one of the scripts invoked at Suspemd/Resume/Hibernate/Wake transitions isn't doing the Right Thing/

Comment: I don't see any DNS or Wireguard related file in `/usr/lib/pm-utils` & `/etc/pm/` folders.